# Retrieve Handle to Windows Explorer's Address bar Edit Control

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, explorer

I need to retrieve full path of most active Windows Explorer instance.

So I have got the handle to Explorer.exe by making a call to 
HWND l_pExplorerhwnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();

Using this handle retrieved, I need to retrieve it's Address bar edit control.
I have used Spy++ and got the class name of edit control as ToolbarWindow32

Now, I have tried to find the window using FindWindowEx using the following code snippet. But I am unable to retrieve it. Please help

```
  HWND l_pExplorerhwnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
  TCHAR l_szTempName[MAX_PATH];

  if(l_pExplorerhwnd)
  {
    ::GetWindowModuleFileName(l_pExplorerhwnd, l_szTempName, MAX_PATH);
    MessageBox(0, l_szTempName, 0, 0);
    if(::FindWindowEx(l_pExplorerhwnd, NULL, L"ToolbarWindow32", NULL))
    {
      ::GetWindowText(::FindWindowEx(l_pExplorerhwnd, NULL, L"ToolbarWindow32", NULL), l_szTempName, MAX_PATH);
      MessageBox(0, l_szTempName, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox(0, L"Error Error ", 0, 0);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox(0, L"Error Error Error", 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Never never never mess with other processes window hierarchies - they can change at any time and it's just rude.
There are APIs like `ShellWindowsClass` in `shdocvw` which might do what you need, but even that sort of thing is frowned upon.
There are almost no legitimate reasons for doing what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what you intend to do with the address bar. Maybe there's a better way. (For example, if you just want to know what the Explorer window is looking at, or if you want to change what it is viewing, you can [use the automation interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx). If you want to incorporate Explorer into your program, then [use the ExplorerBrowser object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/25/10145644.aspx).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, `FindWindowEx` works on direct children of the parent window, not descendants. Hence, you would need to traverse down the children one by one:

```
CabinetWClass
WorkerW
ReBarWindow32
Address Band Root
msctls_progress32
Breadcrumb Parent
ToolbarWindow32
```

Note that this hierarchy is only what it is on my system right now. As mentioned by Tom Whittock, it would be very bad practice to use this. You have no idea whether the window hierarchy could change across updates, or even by design at runtime.

One more comment about your code. Since you are using TCHAR mappings (even though there is usually no reason to use it now unless you are intending to support Win98-), your string literals should be `_T("")` instead of `L""`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tried that and got the answer by checking SPY++. thanks a lot anyways.